# No interface found but works fine everywhere else?

Tags: asp.net, com

I have an ASP.NET website I migrated/converted from classic asp to v4.0
There is a 3rd party DLL which is used and I need to register it using regsvr32.

Now all of this works just fine on my local dev environment but also on a test webserver. My environment runs WS2008R2 Enterprise + all updates and iIS 7.5
The test environment using WS2008R2 Std + all updates and IIS 7.5

I have created several virtual machines with a plain environment to test deployment and that works fine.

The live one however causes a problem. That is running WS2008 Std + updates and IIS 7.0.

When getting to the page in question, I get a runtime error and NO idea where to go about this:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'TAMOnlineUtils.clsMainClass' to interface type 'TAMOnlineUtils._clsMain'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B0B5FC90-90A9-4DD9-A4C6-D779C905B322}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at TAMOnlineUtils.clsMainClass.GetCertFileList(Object& sPath)
   at TAMOnlineWebsite.Report.CalDisplay.DoDisplayCertAndData()
```

Any ideas anyone? Completely stumped.

Comment: AppPool have 'Enable 32-bit applications' turned on?

Comment: Normally it would be but its 32 bit OS so that option does not appear at all. The solution itself is set to ANY CPU. I know it works fine on a 64bit OS and having the app pool set to enable 32 bit apps. The site still runs on 32bit OS.

Comment: I created a local VM with the SAME OS configuration as the live server which is having problems. I can confirm it also works just fine (WS2008 Std + updates. 32 bit). seems to be some issue on the live webserver but not sure where at all. There is an old version of the website which uses classic ASP and it also uses this COM DLL. I use the same version but for the ASP.NET site. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.
There seemed to have been a culprit of the same DLL (perhaps different version) but located in C:\Windows\System32

Not sure why or how that was done but after unregistering that DLL and then deleting the DLL, everything seemed to have worked just fine.

Regression testing is being done on other possible apps affected by the removal of that DLL but it appears its all working fine.

So yes, a conflict there!